# Switching steps with redux-toolkit updates the store state not the view

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

Hello I have a component `StepWizard` with local state.

- https://codesandbox.io/s/react-step-wizard-tusy1

I'm trying to change it to use `redux-toolkit` instead.

- https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-step-wizard-jq7xg

I'm stuck on switching the steps with state provided from store. What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to control the changing the steps inside of `StepWizard` and outside. Can someone please give me a hint what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using `redux` without any library that binds both together. And also passing store manually to components. Everything works smooth wit `react-redux` + `redux-toolkit` set.